# Function that multiplies value with DATEDIFF outcome in a computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble writing a function with a DATEDIFF inside it to use in a computed column.

I have 2 tables:

**Transaction**

tID
cID
carID
eID
tDate
PickupDate
ReturnDate

**Car**

carID
Make
Model
Type
Year

[Data][1]

I need to add an Amount_Due column to the Transaction table that calculates price * number of days.

I know that I need to write a function with a DATEDIFF inside as you can't reference other tables in a computed column. I'm new to SQL and this is the first function I've attempted to write. Here's what I have so far.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TransactionAmountDue(@DateDiff INT, @carID INT)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @price decimal(10,2)
    SELECT @price = Price FROM Car AS TP
        WHERE TP.carID = @carID
    SELECT @DateDiff = DATEDIFF(day, [Transaction].PickupDate, [Transaction].ReturnDate)
    RETURN @DateDiff * @price
END

ALTER TABLE [Transaction] ADD Amount_Due AS 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w20jv.png
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.  Why are you passing in a parameter and then setting in the logic?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, just added an image of my tables. My desired result is adding the calculated column 'Amount_due' that is price * DATEDIFF of PickupDate ReturnDate.